# Pytorch: Devolving into nan Batch losses/Log probs

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm using pytorch as the basis for some machine translation tasks I want to do.
When instantiating my dataset, I have as each torchtext.data.Example a [list(untokenized_string_sentence), untokenized_string_sentence, untokenized_string_sentence]
where untokenized_string_sentence is a just a raw example sentence. I've made sure to be careful about handling the first input as a list in some custom `forward` functions. However, I don't know if the batch loss computation is treating it accordingly, or if I need to be careful about this. I'm simply calling `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` with label smoothing and padding. The result after a couple of batches is a completely `NaN` forward pass (and subsequently, NaN softmax values and loss).

Does anyone know if there is issue in differing types of inputs using PyTorch?

Here are how my types are defined:

```
    src_field = data.Field(init_token=None, eos_token=EOS_TOKEN,
                           pad_token=PAD_TOKEN, tokenize=tok_fun,
                           batch_first=True, lower=lowercase,
                           unk_token=UNK_TOKEN,
                           include_lengths=True)

    trg_field = data.Field(init_token=BOS_TOKEN, eos_token=EOS_TOKEN,
                           pad_token=PAD_TOKEN, tokenize=tok_fun,
                           unk_token=UNK_TOKEN,
                           batch_first=True, lower=lowercase,
                           include_lengths=True)
    prev_inputs_field = data.NestedField(data.Field(init_token=CONTEXT_TOKEN, eos_token=CONTEXT_EOS_TOKEN,
                           pad_token=PAD_TOKEN, tokenize=tok_fun,
                           batch_first=True, lower=lowercase,
                           unk_token=UNK_TOKEN,
                           include_lengths=False), tokenize=sent_fun)
```

Comment: Lower the learning rate

Comment: Please include the code of the model and the loss calculation, otherwise there is no way to identify your problem. Also, you are saying that you use label smoothing, but `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` does not support label smoothing, that's certainly a possible culprit.